# Spring Batch failing to update its state because of RollbackException

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

It seems like Spring Batch is running in the same transaction as the ejbs it is calling. So when we get a Rollback in the ejbs, Spring Batch is not able to update its state in database.

The exception we get is:

```
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.FatalStepExecutionException: JobRepository failure forcing exit with unknown status
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:418)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:262)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:248)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.RollbackException
```

How can we make sure that Spring Batch is able to update its state even when the step fails? Is this a bug in Spring Batch, or have we done anything wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like the problem was in our configuration of joblaunchers.

We have some processes launching other processes and when they used the same taskExecutor instance the rollback rolled back the task itself.

Not 100% sure if this was what fixed the error, but it's working now :-)

Answer (score -1):

Is the batch also running inside an ejb? What is the transaction setting for the ejbs? BMT or CMT? From where in your batch are you invoking the EJB? Reader, Processor, Writer? Listener? Are you trying to handle the exception that causes the rollback on the ejb through regular catch(Exception e) in your code, skip or retry?

Comment: Seems like we had some stopped processes after all. We are invoking ejbs in the writer. No, we are not handling all exceptions. We are letting them fail, and then we have another process restarting them after a while.